# EF Core Property B should be NOT ISNULL(A)

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am using EF Core 6 and have the following question.

In my EF model "`MyModel`", I have a property.

```
public byte[] Thumbnail { get; set; }
```

These thumbnails can have some MB of data. So, I don't load them at the beginning.
I now want an additional EF property in "`MyModel`".

```
// Should be sql equivalent NOT ISNULL(Thumbnail)
public bool HasThumbnail { get; set; }
```

That's needed because

```
// means not loaded yet OR no data at all
if(myModel.Thumbnail == null)
{
}
```

I know, that I can achieve this by using

```
context.MyModel.Select(...)
```

and map my `HasThumbnail` property in code.

But is there a way to tell the EF `ModelBuilder` this behaviour so that it works on the fly?

Comment: create read-only field that tells you if loaded or not

Comment: I dont want to solve it that way for some other reason. Also i am interested in a ef core modelbuilder solution anyway ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution could be [Computed Column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms191250(v=sql.105)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

```cs
public class MyModel {
  public byte[] Thumbnail { get; set; }
  public bool HasThumbnail { get; set; }
}

...

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<MyModel>()
    .Property(e => e.HasThumbnail)
    .HasComputedColumnSql("NOT ISNULL(Thumbnail)");
}
```

Please note that maybe you should refactor `MyModel` to two tables, `MyModel` and `MyModelThumbnailBinary` with one-to-one FK.

Right now you have to use projection for EVERY query for `MyModel` - you really dont want to accidentally include your `Thumbnail` to selection (which can wreak havoc on RAM). And lets face it, accidental`data.MyModelSet.Where(d => d.Date == DateTime.Now.Date).ToArray(); /* ups, i just loaded n*'some MB of data' :( */` is gonna happen sooner or later.

Comment: Another humorous IRL reason to have binaries in another table is when your client say `nice, thank you. Forgot to tell you - we are using free version of MSSQL and, you know, there is limit on database size. And no, purchasing licence is not gonna happen. And no we dont want PgSQL` Moving some big tables (you already have them separated ;) ) to another database is one of possible solution. (It suck, but its possible. Finding new job is another solution.)

Comment: heh, if i remember correctly, `And no we dont want postgresql, our it guy doesn't trust it.`

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I am looking for.
The solution was
`entity.Property(e => e.HasThumbnail).HasComputedColumnSql($@"CASE WHEN {nameof(MyModel.Thumbnail)} IS NULL THEN CAST(0 AS BIT) ELSE CAST(1 AS BIT) END");`
Also thank you for your refactoring tip. I found some cases where I already accidentally 
loaded the Thumbnail because of `.Include(x=>x.MyModel)`